# how can I change the behavior or a function depending on the values passed to it

Tags: java, recursion

so I have this two function, one called, min and the other is called max.
min looks for the minimum it can get starting from POSITIVE_INFINITY, and the max starts from NEGATIVE_INFINITY and try to find the maximum value.

```
private Node Max(State node, int depth, double max, double beta, Player player) {

        if(node.searchLimitReached() || node.over || depth <= 0)
            return new Node(node , heuristic(node, player));

        double value = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        Node nextNode = new Node();
        Node bestNode = new Node();
        Iterator<State> iterator = node.next().iterator();

        while(!node.searchLimitReached() && iterator.hasNext()) {

            nextNode = Min(iterator.next(), depth-1, max, beta, player);
            if(nextNode.value > value) {
                value = nextNode.value;
                bestNode = nextNode;
            }

            if(value >= beta)
                return bestNode;

            max = Math.max(max, value);

        }
        return bestNode;
    }
```

```
    private Node Min(State node, int depth, double alpha, double min, Player player) {

        if(node.searchLimitReached() || node.over || depth <= 0)
            return new Node(node, heuristic(node, player));

        double value = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Node nextNode = new Node();
        Node bestNode = new Node();
        Iterator<State> iterator = node.next().iterator();

        while(!node.searchLimitReached() && iterator.hasNext()) {
            nextNode = Max(iterator.next(), depth-1, alpha, min, player);

            if(nextNode.value < value) {
                value = nextNode.value;
                bestNode = nextNode;
            }

            if(value <= alpha)
                return bestNode;

            min = Math.min(min, value);
        }
        return bestNode;
    }
```

I feel like both method are similar in many aspects and wanted to make into one function that behave different depending on a value passed to it,

I tried many things without success and was wondering if anyone has a good idea on how to approach this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could try something like this (I have not checked the Java code):

```
private Node Extreme(State node, int depth, double a, double b, Player player, boolean which) {
  if(node.searchLimitReached() || node.over || depth <= 0)
      return new Node(node, heuristic(node, player));

  double value = which ? Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  Node nextNode = new Node();
  Node bestNode = new Node();
  Iterator<State> iterator = node.next().iterator();

  while(!node.searchLimitReached() && iterator.hasNext()) {
      nextNode = Extreme(iterator.next(), depth-1, a, b, player, !which);
      if(which && nextNode.value > value || !which && nextNode.value < value) {
          value = nextNode.value;
          bestNode = nextNode;
      }

      if(which && value >= b || !which && value <= a)
          return bestNode;

      if (which) a = Math.max(a, value);
      else b = Math.min(b, value);
  }
  return bestNode;
}
```

Note the `which` variable; if it is `true`, the Minimum is returned, and the Maximum otherwise.

However, I would advise you to never call `Extreme` directly (as this would be unnatural), but rather to redefine your given functions as follows:

```
private Node Min(State node, int depth, double max, double beta, Player player) {
  return Extreme(node, depth, max, beta, player, true);
}

private Node Max(State node, int depth, double alpha, double min, Player player) {
  return Extreme(node, depth, alpha, min, player, false);
}
```

and to call them.

Comment: The more abstract approach would be to pass in Functions or each of the different operations, but there are so many differences (even if they are minor) that it think this is a reasonable solution.